# Съезжает локация во встроенном google map

Tags: google-maps

Использую встраиваемый google map

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/embed?mid=%id%&z=10&ll=55.008353, 82.935733" width="640" height="480">
```

Для того чтобы отображался нужный мне город я установил значения широты и долготы. Но тогда отображается максимально близкое приближение к данной локации. Чтобы отдалиться я поставил z=10, но карта съезжает. т.е. отображается уже локация за пределами этого города.

[image: до отдаления]
[image: после отдаления]

Comment: В каком смысле съезжает? Те же Вилка-ложка, Макдональдс, Речной вокзал итп., но с зумом = 10.

Comment: Добавил изображения. Первое до зума, второе с зумом...при это широта и долгота одинаковые

Comment: У меня всё нормально: https://jsfiddle.net/anatolysukhanov/d7h96jhz/

Comment: Вот и странно что на сайте у себя смотрю - нормально, обновляю страницу - съезжает..потом вновь может стать нормально.